# Hibernate unable to execute schema management to JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have already import the database to myql, But when I run the spring boot application hibernate is throwing error.  i hope someone can help me THANK YOU.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
> Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table
> advertise add constraint FK9lueh92242ckyajg17xr9tcie foreign key
> (country) references country (zh_name)]

**Entity**

```
/**
 * Country
 *
 * @author GS
* @date February 10, 2018
 */
@Data
@Entity
public class Country {
    /**
     * Chinese name
     */
    @Id
    private String zhName;

    /**
     * English name
     */
    private String enName;

    /**
     * Area code
     */
    private String areaCode;
    /**
     * Language
     */
    private String language;

    /**
     * Local currency abbreviation
     */
    private String localCurrency;

    private  int sort;

}
```

**SQL Script**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `country`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `country`;
CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `zh_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `area_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `en_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `local_currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`zh_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You already have the tables, so don't let hibernate manage the schema.

Answer (score 0):

As per your error log, you try to join a country table with the other one. that table gives u the below error.

```
Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table advertise add constraint FK9lueh92242ckyajg17xr9tcie foreign key (country) references country (zh_name)]
```

try to drop those tables from DB and run spring-boot.